# "newest" indicator is not selected when creating tab from a favorite tag

Tags: bug, new-nav

I am not sure this is really a bug / glitch or not, but what happened is not what I would really expect to happen.

Using Firefox 44.0b7

When creating a new tab on the new navigation by clicking on of my favourite tags (list in side bar) the "newest" indicator is not selected. However the question listed are the newest for the specified tag.

[image]

When adding another tag, to filter the "newest" indicator is getting selected. The title of the tab also changes at this point.

[image]